# How to add operations to tensorflow graph which are distributed and defined inside functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to define 2 class and each class with a different graph. Thereby, as a first step I defined a graph for the `class Model`.

The below code snippet will work if the line `with self.graph.as_default():` is removed and run with with a default graph i.e.`with tf.Session() as sess:` .

But I want to define in it in a graph so that I can add another class with a new graph and make those 2 graphs to run in parallel or sequential.

I am new to tensorflow so am still not sure whether the below way of adding operations to the graph is correct or not.

```
import functools
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def doublewrap(function):
    """
    A decorator decorator, allowing to use the decorator to be used without
    parentheses if not arguments are provided. All arguments must be optional.
    """
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and len(kwargs) == 0 and callable(args[0]):
            return function(args[0])
        else:
            return lambda wrapee: function(wrapee, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator


@doublewrap
def define_scope(function, scope=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    A decorator for functions that define TensorFlow operations. The wrapped
    function will only be executed once. Subsequent calls to it will directly
    return the result so that operations are added to the graph only once.
    The operations added by the function live within a tf.variable_scope(). If
    this decorator is used with arguments, they will be forwarded to the
    variable scope. The scope name defaults to the name of the wrapped
    function.
    """
    attribute = '_cache_' + function.__name__
    name = scope or function.__name__
    @property
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(self):
        if not hasattr(self, attribute):
            with tf.variable_scope(name, *args, **kwargs):
                setattr(self, attribute, function(self))
        return getattr(self, attribute)
    return decorator


class Model:

    def __init__(self, image, label):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.image = image
        self.label = label
        self.prediction
        self.optimize
        self.error

    @define_scope(initializer=tf.contrib.slim.xavier_initializer())
    def prediction(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            x = self.image
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 200)
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 200)
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 10, tf.nn.softmax)
        return x

    @define_scope
    def optimize(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            current_error=self.error
            logprob = tf.log(self.prediction + 1e-12) *(1-current_error)  #Here changed ????????????

            cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.label * logprob)
            optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.03)
            trainop = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy) 
        return trainop

    @define_scope
    def error(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            mistakes = tf.not_equal(
                tf.argmax(self.label, 1), tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1))
            me = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))
        return me

    # @define_scope
    # def accuracy(self):
    #     accuracy = tf.reduce_sum()


def main():
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)
    image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    model = Model(image, label)

    with tf.Session(graph=model.graph) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for _ in range(10):
          images, labels = mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
          error = sess.run(model.error, {image: images, label: labels})
          print('Test error {:6.2f}%'.format(100 * error))
          for _ in range(60):
            images, labels = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
            sess.run(model.optimize, {image: images, label: labels})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when the above code is executed am getting the following error message

> ValueError: Tensor("error/Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be
>   from the same graph as Tensor("optimize/Cast:0", shape=(?,),
>   dtype=float32).

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define new graph in your main and define placeholder inside it. Once done, you can pass the graph as a argument to your class.

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self, graph, image, label):
        self.graph = graph
        self.image = image
        self.label = label
        self.prediction
        self.optimize
        self.error

    @define_scope(initializer=tf.contrib.slim.xavier_initializer())
    def prediction(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            x = self.image
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 200)
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 200)
            x = tf.contrib.slim.fully_connected(x, 10, tf.nn.softmax)
            return x

    @define_scope
    def optimize(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            current_error=self.error
            logprob = tf.log(self.prediction + 1e-12) *(1-current_error)  #Here changed ????????????

            cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.label * logprob)
            optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.03)
            trainop = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy) 
            return trainop

    @define_scope
    def error(self):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            mistakes = tf.not_equal(
                tf.argmax(self.label, 1), tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1))
            me = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))
            return me

    # @define_scope
    # def accuracy(self):
    #     accuracy = tf.reduce_sum()


def main():
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)
    graph1 = tf.Graph()
    with graph1.as_default():
        image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
        label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
        model = Model(graph1, image, label)

        with tf.Session(graph=graph1) as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

            for _ in range(10):
              images, labels = mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
              error = sess.run(model.error, {image: images, label: labels})
              print('Test error {:6.2f}%'.format(100 * error))
              for _ in range(60):
                images, labels = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
                sess.run(model.optimize, {image: images, label: labels})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```